# Django, How to move from s3 to CDN?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cloudflare

Our media image files are stored under

```
 http://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/{bucket_nmae}/media/
```

I want to change the url to

`http://static.example.com/media/` and serve them through cloudflare / cloudfront if possible

I've seen tutorials which describe the steps for using s3 as your endpoint or CDN as your endpoint. (https://ruddra.com/posts/aws-boto3-useful-functions/)

But I haven't found one that describes the steps to move from s3 to CDN .

Specifically,

1. Do I need to move files from s3 to CDN manually?

   I think image field itself doesn't have URL attached to it, and once we move (or connect) s3 image to CDN, I believe one can use `http://static.example.com` instead of `http:///s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/{bucket_name}/`
2. What about the image urls stored in the database..

   For instance, when you upload image as a part of a posting, the posting html might have the full image url. These will require DB data migrations.. I belive

Answer (score 0):

To create your custom domain for a bucket you will need:

- create a distribution in CloudFront and set the origin as your bucket
- create a Record Set in Route 53 and point your CloudFront endpoint created in CNAME record.

That is it.